# How to group Entity by other Entity with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, dql

I'am working on Symfony project using Doctrine

So I have 3 Entities :

- Project
- Activity
- Category

A project has severals activities, and an activity has several Categories as well

I'm trying to get all activities, groupped by categories of a project.

What is the proper way of doing that?

I tried with a QueryBuilder, but it seems that you can't group by with an other entity, only with a value (tell me if I'm wrong)

```
$q = $repo->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.project', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'category')
        ->where('p.id = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $projectId)
        ->groupBy('category.id')
        ->getQuery();
    return $q->getResult();
```

**EDIT**
What I really need, is to display a list of categories with according activities inside

```
-Category1
     -Activity1
     -Activity2
     -Activity3
-Category2
     -Activity3
     -Activity4
-Category4
     -Activity1
     -Activity2
     -Activity3
     -Activity4
     -Activity5
```

Is my way to do this good and my code wrong? Or am I wrong everywhere ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: In SQL\DQL, `groupBy` is used to do calculations like counts, averages, sums.. What you really need to do?

Comment: I need to display a list of categories with corresponding activity inside.

Comment: Then, you should fetch and iterate over categories, not actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch and iterate over categories, not actions:

```
$q = $categoryRepo->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->leftJoin('c.actions', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.project', 'p')
    ->where('p.id = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $projectId)
    ->getQuery();
return $q->getResult();
```

And then, in your template (are you using Twig?)

```
{% for category in categories %}
 - {{ category }}
    {% for action in category.actions if action.project.id = 1 %}
     - {{ action }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes i'm using twig ;)
Thanks for your answer, I'm happy to see that there was an easier way :D

What is the "if action.project.id = 1" for ?

Comment: It's to filter only the actions that you want. It's not clean code, I don't know completely who you want to filter out. feel free to write that if condition in an other way

Comment: Ok no problem, Actually, with the "where('p.id = ?1')" Actions are already filtred, so no need to filter again
I checked your code in my project (with refactoring), it works well ! Thanks a lot !